# Form/JavaScript not working on IE 11 with error DOM7011

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, browser-cache, internet-explorer-11

The register button for our ASP.net form, which uses the `__postback` function stopped working on IE 11, from the developer console, it shows:

> **DOM7011**: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337.

Does anyone know how to get around with this? What is this caching thing and why does it mess up forms. I seen similar complaints about this from others.

Answer (score 5):

This issue occurs if the server sends a "Cache-control:no-store" header or sends a "Cache-control:no-cache" header.

Comment: I got this when my page sent "Cache-Control: public, max-age=0". I'm assuming it's because of the `max-age=0`.

Comment: what is the solution ??

Comment: This answer is the explanation of the problem but the solution?

Comment: The server is sending a Cache-control header, so the best solution is to change the server. Secondarily, you may be able to make a different request for the same content. For example, add `"?random=" + Math.random()` to each of your links.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen exactly the same error, also with IE11. In my case the issue occurred when user clicked `<button>` element, which was inside `<form>` tags.

The issue was remedied, by placing the `<button>` outside of `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me when using `window.location.reload()`. Replacing with `window.location = window.location.href` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue before.
I cleared all the IE caches/browsing history/cookies & re-launch IE. It works after caches removed.

You may have a try. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this exception was being caused by an unsecure ajax call on an SSL enabled site. Specifically: my url was `'http://...'` instead of `'https://...'`. I just replaced it with `'//...'`.

To me, the error was misleading, and hopefully this may help anyone landing here after searching for the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this when click on a html , it is fixed by adding type = "button" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same console warning, when an ajax request was firing, so my form was also not working properly.

I disabled caching on the server's ajax call with the following response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
```

After this, the form was working. Refer to the server language (c#, php, java etc) you are using on how to add these response headers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Internet Explorer, and got the same error number.  The culprit was an HTML comment.  I know it sounds unbelievable, so here is the story.

I saw a series of 6 articles on the Internet.  I liked them, so I decided to download the 6 Web-Pages and store them on my Hard Drive.  At the top of each page, was a couple of HTML `<a>` Tags, that would allow you to go to the next article or the previous article.  So I changed the href  attribute to point to the next folder on my Hard Drive, instead of the next URL on the Internet.

After all of the links had been re-directed, the Browser refused to display any of the Web-Pages when I clicked on the Links.  The message in the Console was the Error Number that was mentioned at the top of this page.

However, the real problem was a Comment.  Whenever you download a Web-Page using Google Chrome, the Chrome Browser inserts a Comment at the very top of the page that includes the URL of the location that you got the Web-Page from.  After I removed the Comment at the top of each one of the 6 Pages, all of the Links worked fine ( although I continued to get the same Error Message in the Console. )

Answer (score -5):

Go to

`Tools > Compatibility View settings > Uncheck the option "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"`.

Click on `Close`. It may re-launch the page and then your problem would be resolved.

Comment: if you are not able to locate "Tools", enable Command bar by right click on the header of IE11 window

Comment: I tried this to debug, and the warning still appeared.