# Back Navigation Caching - IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, caching, browser

When I am running web application on IE 11, getting warning message as below:

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For
> more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Same question is posted in: [Form/JavaScript not working on IE 11 with error DOM7011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21920864/2190889)
How to remove this warning message from my console panel?

Comment: The error code itself contains a perfect reference to all the possible answers on this question.

Comment: How to enable back & forward caching?

Comment: Is it so hard to follow the link provided and check all the requirements on your page are satisfied?

Comment: As at time of writing, the page at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337 does not contain any documentation on code DOM7011, and the word "caching" does not appear in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo that floods the F12 debugger console with that DOM7011 message.  Just click and change the select options.  It'll produce that message each time.

I think it's a bug.

https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XaEpiYlM3WWhicWM     (demo)

http://xtzq5a-ch3301.files.1drv.com/y2pXSI1a8_5CbKRUM2unAd8No0dZiD3GFbXYw8C4SY7UHmP4j8f2UNFl5q41_Wo_tYKZiOq0NTf4YzV8YK_5k1UAS1uTdpoihgh_bWhYTa0RY4/DOM7011.png     (screenshot)

Comment: Also the Microsoft doc says caching is disabled on SSL pages, but my page is over SSL and It appears the cache is still being used.  Another bug?