# HTML Select not working in https page internet explorer with DOM7011 error

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, ms-office, excel-addins

I am trying to create an app in an excel add-in.  The browser there will not allow me to use a select html tag.

example:

```
            <select id="pattern">
                <option value="square">Square</option>
                <option value="rotatedSquare">Rotated Square</option>
                <option value="triangular">Triangular</option>
                <option value="rotatedTriangular">Rotated Triangular</option>
            </select>
```

Excel add-ins are served using https, and the error I get in the console everytime I try to change the selection is:

DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.

It links to msdn information page here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.DOM7011)

Any idea on what my options are to fix this?

I saw similar questions asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920864/form-javascript-not-working-on-ie-11-with-error-dom7011), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152174/back-navigation-caching-ie?noredirect=1&lq=1) but no real clear solution given to fixing the issue.

Comment: Datalist doing the same thing, please help internet, this is so annoying.

Comment: Well, just went with radio selects instead.  If anyone comes across this and knows the solution, I'd love to hear it.  There are 3 unsolved stack overflow questions concerning this, without a really valid solution.